Kolkata metropolitan area shapefile
I have searched everywhere but I could not find the figure to digitize or any shapefiles through which I can clip out the shapefiles. How can I make a shapefile for Kolkata metropolitan area?

You can do it yourself.
Based on Wikipedia info and Overpass: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1Viw. You can run the query in Overpass and export it as GeoJSON, then convert to shapefile if needed.

